# Is it a good idea to learn LINQ first, then SQL?

Tags: sql, linq

I know that in most cases it`s more useful to learn more complicated technology/language and then easy one than vice versa.
But, actually, time to do university tasks is limited. If I first learn LINQ, then go for SQL, would it be hard for me to use and learn sql?
**EDIT**
The task I need to do is to work with database and get some data from it, so the question is almost about LINQ to SQL.

Comment: Re the edit - then say so ;-p

Comment: the point is I don`t want to stick with only C# and .NET platform for the rest of my life, it`s highly likely that this is what I`ll do for living, but that`s not all I want to know

Comment: Well, SQL (in variants such as TSQL, etc) is truly ubiquitous. LINQ is  .NET specific. But you need to decide what is important short term (to pass the course) and long term (career). They may be different - but which is more immediate?

Comment: the most important thing now is to do the task and meet the deadline:)
the subject we studying is .NET framework

Comment: Then I think the definition of "good idea" changes, and you already know what you have to do given time constraints, no?

Comment: but if majority of opinions of StackOverflowers told me learn SQL first, then I'll highly likely use it instead of LINQ, because time constraints isn`t the main factor for me - it`s the right way to do things, and nothing else

Comment: In my opinion time at courses should not be wasted to learn any of end-point layers, .NET, Java (C++ maybe an exception). General concepts and theories are what you're in university after.

Comment: but still, this is what our course of OOP consists of - 3 half-years of C++ and one half-year of .NET

Comment: I hear you. With C++ you not only learn language but get a better understanding of how the programs are working "behind the scenes". With .NET/Java you won't get anything beyond some framework knowledge. And don't worry, LINQ is very simple, look at the examples, ask questions here and you have it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is a bad idea.

And if today's universities teach you LINQ instead of giving you foundation to build your knowledge upon, I can only feel sorry and pity for their students.

Time is always limited. Don't waste it on things that are subject to constant change.

SQL will be there tomorrow, LINQ.... well who knows.

SQL is applicable anywhere, LINQ only in .NET world.

Either LINQ or something else, it will be easy to "learn" it afterwards. When you have the knowledge of SQL, it will just me a matter of hours/days/weeks, hardly longer.

Comment: How is this offensive?  This is true!  I'm a LINQ fanboy and there has already been a lot of discussion about entities and LINQ's future.  General SQL knowledge will go farther.

Comment: universities don`t teach us LINQ, they want us to get the job done and that `s all. so, the technology we pick up to do this is all about out knowledge and choice and preference. LINQ is just my alternative for not to dive deep in SQL

Answer (score 9):

Well, the 2 things are very different. LINQ (in the pure sense) isn't actually related to databases *at all* - it can be used quite happily just with in memory objects, or against web services, etc.

If you are mainly interested in writing better .NET code, then learn LINQ - but learn it *properly* - perhaps pick up [C# in Depth](http://www.manning.com/skeet/), for example - which covers it very well in the last few chapters.

If you want to know about databases, then sure: learn SQL (such as TSQL) - but understand the differences. Databases are good if you need to write enterprise software, but not necessarily if you just want to do simple tasks.

**edit re edit to the question**

If you are just getting simple data in and out of the database, then you probably don't need to know much about SQL. Just use LINQ-to-SQL (or whatever tool), and let the ORM tooling worry about it.

Answer (score 4):

SQL is a standard, learn the standard.

More precisely :

- learn database theory
- learn CODD algebra
- then pick up a "common database", do some tutorials on it, ...

I personnaly really like PostgreSQL [tutorial](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/tutorial.html)

Comment: i do not know the differences between SQL92, SQL99, SQL2003, SQL20008 ... but for a beginner I don't think it really matters

Answer (score 4):

Learn SQL first, then LINQ.

That way you'll understand how LINQ-to-SQL is working behind the scenes, but you'll also know enough to be able to cope when LINQ can't do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I submit that you cannot effectively use LINQ unless you have SQL knowledge. If you don't understand, at a minimum, the following, you cannot effectively query a database in any fashion:

```
select
insert
delete
update
joins
group by
boolean algebra
relational theory
set theory
```

Learning SQL will give you the concepts you need even if you use LINQ later.

Answer (score 1):

Sql. However you could play with [linq pad](http://www.linqpad.net/)  for a while - it is a freeware and realize that LINQ is a nice hybrid between SQL and C#